# Instance Injection Android Unit Test

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I am very new in writing the unit test cases. Currently I am writing the unit test cases of a Camera Application using robolectric and roboguish. In code segment I am opening a camera like this

```
private Camera safeCameraOpen(final int id) {
        boolean qOpened = false;
        try {
            // stopPreviewAndFreeCamera();
            this.mCamera = Camera.open(id);
            qOpened = (this.mCamera != null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logErrorMessage("Error in open camera > Log captured", "Fail to open camera >> camera Id " + id
                    + ">> Message" + e.getMessage());
        }
        return this.mCamera;
    }
```

In writing the unit test case, I want to use this opened instance like the following way

```
this.mShadowCamera = Robolectric.shadowOf(mCamera);
```

here mCamera instance should be same which i have opened in code.

The problem is I dont know how can i use the same instance to write the code.

I am trying to read roboguish but not able to understand it properly. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ShadowCamera's [getLastOpenedCameraId()](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowCamera.html#getLastOpenedCameraId%28%29) to assert that it is equal to the id you are passing in